# 'Drillable' report - Very large number of members in the hierarchy (1.5 million plus)

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

The problem: I have relatively complex MDX query.
About 25 MDX sets on columns
Dimension "Exposures" on rows.
The dimension has following levels:
Level1:Bank_unit
Level2:Obligor
Level3:Exposure 
The domension "Exposures" is supposed to be drillable on my report(user wants to be able to review data that make up the total down to Exposure level)

Now, the Bank_unit can have up 100-4 million of exposures.
This is where the problem is.

I am unable to use filtering/ranking/sorting as it significantly slows down the report. Using these features makes the report unusable.

When I do not use these tricks and show all obligors (using "pager" feature on our reporting SW) ....it works fine for Bank_units with up to 100000 obligors, but it takes looooooooong time to retrieve obligors for Bank_units with, say 2 million of obligors.

I do not see any logical hierarchy level I could insert between Bank_uni and Obligor levels to break numbers into manageable groups.

Any tips how to deal with this situation, and keep that cricial "drillability"?

Thanks

Comment: On the surface, this sounds like your user wants organized data, but doesn't want to pay the price to organize it.  Is the problem just the real-time wait?  Is the data available to organize *before* the user requests the report?  Can you thread or classify it ahead of time?  Your volume gets into big-data range; do you have flexibility to change handling engines?

Comment: yes,i can organize data before,

Comment: i just need to be able to drill into hierarchy. and get the result within,say max 30secs.

Comment: i can change the hierarchy,structure just need to be meaningful